# Getting the exact view object that is clicked inside a row in a ListActivity set to ListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, listadapter

I have an Activity that extends ListActivity: `MyActivity extends ListActivity`. I set the `contentView` of `MyActivity` to a layout which has an `android:id/list` in it. Each row in this list comes from another layout file `rowLayout.xml`. (Sorry, unable to post a row image, my reputation is < 10) Among other views, a row has an ImageButton to delete the item (record).

I fetch the list items from a SQLite database into a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and set `MyActivity` to a `ListAdapter`, with the following pseudo-snippet:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String myColumns[] = {DBContract.Columns._LOGO,....};
int myViews[] = {R.id.ivMasterLogo....};

Cursor gsDBCursor = sqlDB.query(DBContract.MY_TABLE, 
                                myColumns,
                                null, null, null, null, null);      

ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                                            R.layout.master_row_layout, 
                                            gsDBCursor, 
                                            myColumns, 
                                            myViews, 0);

setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

I am ***not using any custom adapter***.

The task is to delete the row when the `ImageButton` is clicked. My problem is:

- if I use the `ImageButton`'s onClick(), I am unable to find which row in the list was clicked.
- if I use the `onListItemClick()` method, I am unable to find if the `ImageButton` was clicked inside the row.

I am sure there's a simple solution, but I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: set the tag of your ImageButton to the row id: ImageButton.setTag(id), in onClick you can use getTag() to get id

Comment: Thanks for the blazing fast reply, pskink! But **where exactly** do I set it?

Comment: in `getView()` or if you dont want to extend SCA use `ViewBinder`